# Jenkins CI - Unable to sent post build email to distribution list

Tags: jenkins

I am unable to send post build emails to a distribution list (i.e. My_Team@company.com).
When I add a distribution name to the 'Test e-mail recipient' option within Configure System[Jenkins], Jenkins reports that the email was sent successfully even though members of the distribution list do NOT receive the test email.

The only way I can get Jenkins to send the email is to add each recipient to the list.

Comment: My first step would be to check with the administrators of your email server and ask them what it did with the email going to  My_Team@company.com. You've shown that Jenkins *can* send emails and a lot of places have rules in place regarding which users or servers can access distribution lists.

Comment: I found that the email "management" stuff in Jenkins wasn't that useful, but it didn't matter.  I didn't have that many email end points so I set up my own aliases in /etc/aliases on the jenkins server and then emailed "foo@localhost" and let the MTA explode it and send on as required.  Worked fine

Comment: @erman8 - please select and mark an answer to this

Answer (score 1):

1. First I would recommend you to use Email-ext(Editable Email notification) plugin for emails instead of default email for Jenkins. You can trigger how ever the way you want the emails out through the advanced configuration.
2. Check the configuration in Manage jenkins-> Configure System -> smtp mail server(at the bottom of the page)

Answer (score 1):

Agreed with @matt_freake as mentioned in comments you would certainly want to figure out the access to the distribution list mentioned.
With some past experience, I would also suggest you might not want to be missing the chance of receiving the e-mail notifications for any job that you trigger for which you can make sure your e-mail `Advanced Settings` are set as depicted in the pic below :
[image]

Answer (score 0):

I'm having the same problem & don't really know what causes it.

I suspect it's on the Outlook / internal email server side though, rejecting it due to incomplet / unreliable headers or something. I've seen elsewhere that it can get filtered to Junk